# Grab the corresponding object on click of a dynamic button

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, events, dynamic

I've created some dynamic content using an array containing objects. Now, my dynamic content has a button which will help me to get the corresponding object from the 'myData' array on click.

I'm confused on how do I grab the corresponding object from the myData array.

Could you please help me with that?

Here's the code:

```js
var myData = [
  { 
 'car': 'Ford',
 'color': 'Black',
 'model': 'Figo'     
  }, { 
 'car': 'Ford',
 'color': 'Red',
 'model': 'Endeavour'     
  },{ 
 'car': 'Jaguar',
 'color': 'White',
 'model': 'F-Type'     
  },
];
 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#createData').click(function(){
 myData.forEach(function(obj){
   $('.container').append(
  $('<div>').addClass('parent').append(
    $('<div>').append(
   $('<label>').text('Car: '),
   $('<span>').text(obj.car)
    ),
    $('<div>').append(
   $('<br /><label>').text('Model: '),
   $('<span>').text(obj.model)
    ),
    $('<br /><button>').text('Click Me').addClass('getData')
  )
   )
 });
  });   
});

$(document).on('click', '.getData', function(obj){
  var myColor = $(this);
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<button id="createData">Create Data</button>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. Basically we attach an index to every button in your loop and use this unique index to access your array afterwards. Just have a look in the console while clicking to see the result.

```js
var myData = [
  { 
 'car': 'Ford',
 'color': 'Black',
 'model': 'Figo'     
  }, { 
 'car': 'Ford',
 'color': 'Red',
 'model': 'Endeavour'     
  },{ 
 'car': 'Jaguar',
 'color': 'White',
 'model': 'F-Type'     
  },
];

var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#createData').click(function(){
 myData.forEach(function(obj){
   $('.container').append(
  $('<div>').addClass('parent').append(
    $('<div>').append(
   $('<label>').text('Car: '),
   $('<span>').text(obj.car)
    ),
    $('<div>').append(
   $('<br /><label>').text('Model: '),
   $('<span>').text(obj.model)
    ),
    $('<br /><button data="'+i+'">').text('Click Me').addClass('getData')
  )
   )
      i++;
 });
  });   
});

$(document).on('click', '.getData', function(obj){
  var myColor = $(this);
  console.log(myData[obj.currentTarget.attributes[0].nodeValue]);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="createData">Create Data</button>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Is this what you wanted or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Thanks a lot..but there has to be an option to add on click event to the dynamic button wherein I can pass the entire object as an argument...